What is the Likelihood Formula for an Error in Variable Model?
I am comparing different models ability to explain my joint observation of (X,Y) with AIC for which I need the likelihood.
How can I calculate the likelihood of (X,Y) for the error in variable model specified here on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models#Motivating_example
and screen shotted here:

Is it simply L(η)*L(ε)?  Are there any other commonly reported likelihood metrics for the regression?  For example, I know for a standard regression y = α + βx + ε, that L(ε) equals L(y|x), right?  I would be interested in these types of likelihoods as well.
Thank you!
EDIT BELOW HERE:
Okay, I've updated my model.  One of the major problems I was having from the wikipedia page is it says nothing about the values of x* and y*.  Is it okay if I use this specification?
$x_{i}* = \alpha_{x} + \beta_{x}x_{i}$
$y_{i}* = \alpha_{r} + \beta_{r}x_{i}*$
$\epsilon_{i} = y_{i}* - \alpha_{y} - \beta_{y}y_{i}$
$\eta_{i} = x_{i} - x_{i}*$
One possible problem I see with the model is that it looks like I can minimize the error ($\eta$ and $\epsilon$) to zero by setting $\alpha_{x}=0,\beta_{x}=1$ and then set $\beta_{r}=0$, so $y*=\alpha_{r}$ and let $\alpha_{y}=\alpha_{r}$ and $beta_{y}=0$.  And it doesn't seem correct that I can always minimize the error to zero.  But is there a quick fix?  Or even just a better approach?

Do you mean likelihood or probability?  The likelihood function is a function of the parameters, in this case, $\alpha, \beta$, and so forth, conditional upon the observed data $X$ and $Y$.  The probability is what you would say is "of $Y$".

i want to find the "best fit" for the parameters for my edited model (above).  I should minimize the weighted mean square error, but I don't know how to do that because my error has a complex covariance structure, specifically, eta ~ N(0,Sigma), where cov(eta_i,eta_j) is not zero.  So instead I plan to fit the parameters by maximum likelihood.  But do i minimize the sum of Lik(eta)+Lik(epsilon) or their product Lik(eta)*Lik(epsilon) or some other quantity?  Whatever I do needs to allow for a significance test where I fix parameters.  I was thinking doing a likelihood ratio test is easiest.
